# How do i trigger a popup on a webpage using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I know how to make the popup come up when page opens but I'd like to know how to trigger it when they try to close the page.
Help?

Comment: To be sure, aren't you confusing Java with JavaScript? Your question is at least hard to understand. Please edit and improve.

Comment: 1) Applet could do this (theoretically) using a call to showDocument() with a target of "_blank" called from within the "destroy()" method (presuming it is called by the browser/JRE combo. - a rash assumption). 2) JS is well suited to this task and would not require loading a JRE.  See dmcnelis' answer for details. 3) I added the JS tag to hopefully grab the attention of the JS developers - Java developers write the worst JS on the planet (IMO).  4) User's generally **hate** pop-ups, and especially 'page exit pop-ups'.  Most browser plug-ins and virus checkers offer tools to suppress them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and answer assuming you meant to say javascript.

What you can do is invoke a function on unloading the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload=functionname();
```

Here is a reference [doc](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Event-Handlers-Reference/onBeforeUnload.htm)